# Efficient DOM Selecting Techniques - Is selecting by attribute to slow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, placeholder

I am using a script to make all inputs having a placeholder in browsers that dont yet support that feature.

In that script I am using

```
$('input[placeholder]').each(function() {
```

to select all the elements to act on.

I was wondering if that maybe would be to slow since its not a very specific select like

```
$('#input').each(function() {
```

which I know selects way faster (but I dont want to specify all the id´s separately).

Would you recommend adding classes to all the inputs with placeholders atribute like so:

```
$('.iHaveaPlaceholder').each(function() {
```

to make selecting faster (I think selecting by class is faster than by atribute). But this would misuse the purpose of css classes only meaning to style and it would fill up the dom.

Do you have any suggestions or techniques as to improve tasks like these?

Comment: oh cool, didn´t know that. seems like selecting by class is indeed faster.

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and made a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/attr-selector/3) for comparing the selectors `input[placeholder]`, `.hasPlaceholder` and `input` with a [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter).

Now that we have some numbers to think about, lets talk about why you want to know.

When are you doing this search for `'input[placeholder]'`?  Hopefully only once.  If you do either of these selectors in a modern browser, they will be pretty speedy (the number is operations per second....).  However if you know you are only running this selectors on browsers that don't support placeholders, of the three methods listed, the `.hasPlacehoder` is actually the slowest in IE 6, with the custom filter winning.  You want to try testing performance in the browsers that this code will actually affect..

Feel free to add your own selectors, or even better closer to your exact HTML to that page and solicit some browser testing!

**Edit:** I added [`input.hasPlaceholder`](http://jsperf.com/attr-selector/4) to the race on a new perf...

Comment: +1 Not only did I have no idea thas JSPerf existed, the results are surprising! (Using a filter is twice as fast as using `input[placeholder]` for me)

Comment: @Kragen - `$('input')` gets optimized to [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) and then run quickly through the filter function.  In browsers that can't support [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) it will probably be the fastest..

Comment: Wow actual profiling? Who'd of thunk it? Great test and really surprising results! I really expected the element selector to be quicker than a class selector. Baffling.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a massive DOM, I don't think the performance difference should really come into play. Setting a whole lot of classes for the purposes of 'optimizing', like you said, messes with the logical structure of your document.

Selecting by class, without providing a context, will still cause the entire DOM to be traversed. Same goes for selecting by element I think. Using placeholder classes here is definitely not the answer. What you are wanting to do is find all input elements with a particular attribute - and you're using the correct selector for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could give your form an id and then use `$("#theForm input[placeholder]")` which will cut down on how many elements the selector has to consider.

Comment: Yes, but I have many forms and dont want to specify each one.

Comment: I guess it's not a win for you in that case. Selecting on some qualifier of "input" should at least be using `document.getElementsByTagName` or something like. So if you reckon checking the class is faster, maybe $("input.iHaveaPlaceholder").

Comment: I'd be curious to compare $("form input[placeholder]") with $("input[placeholder]"). We all know inputs should be in forms but I guess an isolated input elsewhere would match too, proving the engine is looking at the whole DOM. Narrowing to the form element should boost the performance a tiny bit.

Comment: CSS selectors are applied [right to left](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/). While jQuery might do something different, if it uses the browser's native `querySelector` function, it actually matches all `input[placeholder]` and then filters out the ones that aren't a descendant of `#theForm`.

Comment: i just found out about this testingwebsite. i dont think its faster (if the testing setup is right) http://jsperf.com/attr-selector/2

Comment: @Marcel - You are half correct --- There is virtually no difference in Chrome 9... What about IE6 or some of the dog slow browsers... You might be surprised...  Don't be so concerned about the speed in the FASTEST engine out there... Lots of things are optimized, and Chrome has `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

**It's not slow** (have you tested or just speculating?). **But use classes if it is.**

Comment: Interesting paradoxal answer ;-)

Comment: Isn't it? :) No, I mean I bet he doesn't have any performance problem, he's just worried for no good reason. But classes are faster, that's fact.